# Open square bracket array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

Good day everyone! 
After array is pushed from JSON

```
 var users  = []
 users.push(data?.Users)
```

I received this type of response when opening it on debug. I just want to know, is it possible to get rid off square brackets at start point or there is any other options how to parse it. Also added screenshot of data.[image]

Comment: just use,  `users = data?.Users`

Comment: What your code does is push the array `data?.Users` as a single element of your array `users`. So `users` is an array of arrays with one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure the response

```
users.push(...data?.Users)
```

Comment: Yeah, but `users = data?.Users` is simpler and more direct in the OP's case. There may be reasons, though, to do it this way which could be explained.

Comment: I agree, but maybe there are other elements in the array.

Comment: His first code statement is `var users = []`. But to your point, you should explain that scenario in your answer. Explain the advantage of your approach and under what circumstances one might want to do it this way.